# Docker won't update php version

Tags: php, docker

I have a docker container running PHP version 7.1. I require 7.3 so I am trying to update the version.
The docker-compose.yml file has the following:

```
php: image: nanoninja/php-frm:S{PHP_VERSION}
```

If I check the .env I see:

```
PHP_VERSION=latest
```

There is a link to a repository with 'tags' that can be used other than 'latest'. One of these is "7.3.10" which is what I changed my .env to use. I also did this:

```
docker pull nanoninja/php-fpm:7.3.10
```

I get a confirmation that the 7.3.10 is pulled and up to date. I then do "docker-compose down" and "docker-compose up -d". If I then do php-v I still see the previous version.

What is the magic required to achieve such a simple task. The documentation is non-existent.

Comment: I am not totally sure, but with docker you should not rely on `:latest` tag. The latest version of PHP today 7.4.3.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - yes but regardless you'd expect my php version to be the latest in that case - I can't get rid of 7.1

Comment: Try `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up` - Ref: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3574

Comment: Try `docker system prune`

Comment: Ok so phpinfo() is displaying the corrct php version, just different at command line, I believe this is a path env var issue in that case.